# Product attribute show/hide in admin depending on other attribute value

Tags: attributes

I have a product attribute but it is only relevant if another product attribute is selected (a dropdown yes/no) value.

In the admin view I would like show/hide my custom attribute depending on the yes/no value of the other system attribute.

I believe this is possible using javascript but im not sure how to get the javascript on the page with my attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use 'depends' tag in system.xml in field which we have to show/hide depends on 'yes/no' field.

Below are syntax you can use:

```
<depends><enabled>1</enabled></depends>
```

In above syntax 'enabled' is a field with 'yes/no' values.

Above code is for system >> Configuration settings .

To add any field depends on 'yes/no' in product form you can use below code:

```
  $productField = $fieldset->addField('enabled', 'select', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Enabled'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Enabled'),
        'name'      => 'enabled',
        'options'   => array(
            0 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No'),
            1 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes'),  
        ),
        'onclick' => 'toggleYesNo()',
    ));
    $productField->setAfterElementHtml('
        <script>
        function toggleFixedShipping() {
           $("idToShowHide").toggle();
        }
        </script>
    ');
```

Here 'idToShowHide' id will be show/hide field's ID.

I hope it solves your concern.

Answer (score 4):

Check out `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Tax\Rate\Form.php` for an example of how Magento does this, which is slightly different than Bijal Bhavsar's method.

**First it defines it's Yes/No select**

```
$fieldset->addField('zip_is_range', 'select', array(
    'name'    => 'zip_is_range',
    'label'   => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Zip/Post is Range'),
    'options' => array(
        '0' => Mage::helper('tax')->__('No'),
        '1' => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Yes'),
    )
));
```

**Then another field, (which will be hidden sometimes)**

```
$fieldset->addField('zip_from', 'text', array(
    'name'      => 'zip_from',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Range From'),
    'required'  => true,
    'maxlength' => 9,
    'class'     => 'validate-digits'
));
```

**Then it sets the dependance, right above `_prepareForm()`**

```
$this->setChild(
    'form_after',
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('zip_is_range', 'zip_is_range')
        ->addFieldMap('zip_from', 'zip_from')
        ->addFieldDependence('zip_from', 'zip_is_range', '1')
);
```

**Note on prefixes**

If you at any point set a prefix like this: `$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('mymodule_');` then you'll need to put the prefix in the dependence block like so:

```
$this->setChild(
    'form_after',
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('mymodule_zip_is_range', 'mymodule_zip_is_range')
        ->addFieldMap('mymodule_zip_from', 'mymodule_zip_from')
        ->addFieldDependence('mymodule_zip_from', 'mymodule_zip_is_range', '1')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add js files on the admin product page using the layout xml files:
in  tag:
you can add either a js file in head tag:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>path to js</name></action>
</reference>
```

Note: this should be in the magento skin adminhtml folder.

Or you could add a js block if you also need some php logic:
For example:

```
<reference name="js">            
   <block type="core/template" name="custom.js" template="my path to js phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Note: this file should go in the adminhtml theme

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display fields only if Select is YES
Use below tag inside fields you want to display only on YES

You have to use `depends` tag, it can be used to declare dependencies to other fields. Is used to only show specific fields/groups when a given field has a value of 1

```
<field id="A_UNIQUE_FIELD_ID" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="0" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1" type="select">
   <label>Feature Flag Example</label>
   <comment>This field is an example for a basic yes or no select.</comment>
   <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
<depends> <!-- This field will only be visible if the field with the id A_UNIQUE_FIELD_ID is set to value 1 -->
     <field id="A_UNIQUE_FIELD_ID">1</field>
</depends>
```